# OpenLayers Plugin error: Google

Tags: javascript, google, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I've seen other related questions concerning this issue, but I can't figure it out. QGIS doesn't show me Google Layers from the OpenLayers Plugin, and the following message comes out:

This page was unable to display a Google Maps element. Please contact the site administrator. If you are the administrator of this site, please check the JavaScript console or check the following page for troubleshooting: http://g.co/mapsJSApiErrors

My knowledge on QGIS is pretty basic.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Avoid the OpenLayers Plugin.

The plugin has only got few bugfixes lately, but no active development.

As an alternative, try the new QuickMapServices plugin.

For license reasons, it does not contain Google Maps by default. But you can activate them with `Web -> QuickMapServices -> Settings -> More Sevices -> Get contributed pack`.